# Create a strong password in Groovy with special character

Tags: groovy

I would like to create a strong password in groovy with alphabets both small and Capital and numbers and special chars.

Following are the required special chars:

> ~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'",<.>/?

I am using the below code but I would also like to at least one Special Character in my password.

```
 def pass_length = 15;

    def pool = ['a'..'z','A'..'Z',0..9,'_'].flatten();
    Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

    def passChars = (0..pass_length - 1).collect { pool[rand.nextInt(pool.size())] };
    def PASSWORD = passChars.join();
```

Currently its creating a alphanumeric password only. Any quick changes I can make to the code? Help me as I am new to use groovy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pick a random special character, and put it a random position in the generated password. This will make sure there's at least one special character in the password.

Also, why not adding the special characters to your dictionary as well? In this way there are more possibilities that a special character will end up in the final string.

```
def pass_length = 15;

def special = ['~' ,'`', ...] // you get the idea...
def pool = ['a'..'z','A'..'Z',0..9,'_'].flatten().plus(special);
Random rand = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());

def passChars = (0..pass_length - 1).collect { pool[rand.nextInt(pool.size)] };
def specialChar = special[rand.nextInt(special.size)]
passChars[rand.nextInt(passChars.size)] = specialChar
def PASSWORD = passChars.join();
```

Answer (score 0):

The below code generates a random password of a specified length using the specified base alphabet and specific number of special characters from a "special characters alphabet":

```
def alphabet    = ('a'..'z') + ('A'..'Z') + ('0'..'9')
def specials    = /~`!@#$%^&*()-_=+[{]}\|;:'",<.>\/?/

def random      = new Random()
def r           = { max -> random.nextInt(max) } // utility closure

// to test - generate 10 passwords and print them on stdout
10.times { 
  // generate a 15 character password with the given alphabet and specials 
  // set with one or two special characters randomly inserted
  def password = randomPassword(r, alphabet, specials, 15, (1..2))
  println password
}

def randomPassword(r, alphabet, specials, passwordLen, specialsRange) {
  // generate non-specials password
  def password  = randomChars(r, alphabet, passwordLen)

  // cointoss to determine number of specials
  def nSpecials = specialsRange.from + r(specialsRange.to-specialsRange.from+1)

  // insert that number of random specials picked from the specials set
  nSpecials.times { 
    password[r(password.size())] = specials[r(specials.size())]
  }

  password.join()
}


def randomChars(r, alphabet, length) {
  (1..length).collect { alphabet[r(alphabet.size())] }
}
```

and a sample run:

```
~> groovy solution.groovy 
06HT.Q5J4OOvN}S
U1h28bRcu{o)0l2
VxhMSD@6H7Qt(vH
9Bt!G2v.LT0u4ES
r1=RyWJO6R}x2Gl
sOBimChqOY3P1#x
5A]V4iiUQXkZdXv
R1iwlkZT-Ou;BrO
HbNAF>W4NRFSYRF
evuLb~ma%fzcSuA

~>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing this here for the record. Creates passwords from length 6 to 100 (these values can be changed in the code).

```
//Author: Rinaldi Michael
//Last Modified: 14th Dec 2022
//Password from length 6 to 100
 
import java.io.*
import java.lang.*
 
String passwords=""

            Random rnd = new Random()
            int randomNumber = rnd.nextInt(100)
            if(randomNumber==0 || randomNumber<6)
                randomNumber+=6
            String[] passwordCharacters=["a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k","l","m","n","o","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","w","x","y","z"
                      ,"A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"
                      ,"!","@","%","^","&","*","(",")","-","+","=",".","/",">","<",";",":","|"]
     
            for(int p=0;p<randomNumber;)
            {
                try
                {
                passwords = passwords+passwordCharacters[rnd.nextInt(passwordCharacters.size())]
                p++
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    p++
                }
            }
 
return passwords
```

Comment: It's important to not just post code, but to also include a description of what the code does and why you are suggesting it. This helps others understand the context and purpose of the code, and makes it more useful for others who may be reading the question or answer. @Rinaldi Michael .